# Динамическое получение списка выбора для формы

Tags: django

Есть простая форма

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICE = [(1, 1), (2, 2)]
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICE)
```

Здесь CHOICE сразу указан, а как его динамически получать во вьюхе? Вьюшка отображает форму и в зависимости от того какой список получает, тот и будет в списке выбора.
Если во вьюхе получить экземпляр формы, то не меняется все равно

```
form = MyForm()
form.CHOICE = [(3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

Comment: перепишите __init__ функцию класса с choices.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, choices=[(1, 1), (2, 2)], *args, **kwargs)
       self.choices = choices
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

Далее примерно так:

```
form = MyForm(choices = [(3, 3), (4, 4)])
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде, все логично и правильно, но пайчарм подчеркивает красным self в этой строке  choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=self.choices), типа, нужно импортировать   NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @Дмитрий  там без self надо.

Comment: первым делом убрал его, теперь choices подчеркивает ))))  NameError: name 'choices' is not defined